# New model field is not showing in admin page on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have a problem when adding a new field to my models.py in PythonAnywhere. My models.py looks like the following, and I recently added the description field to it.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    shortcontent = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    language = models.IntegerField(choices=LANGUAGE, default=0)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I did run the makemigrations and python manage.py migrate commands, but the description field is not showing on my admin page:

[image: no description field in here]

My admin.py looks like this:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'status','created_on')
    list_filter = ("status",)
    search_fields = ['title', 'content', 'description']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
    class Media:
        js = ('ckeditor.js',)
        # do not write '/static/ckeditor.js' as Django automatically looks
        # in the static folder

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

What can I do to make sure the description field shows up on my admin page. I am using Python 3.8 in Pythonanywhere.

Comment: Did you reload the web app? If you change the source code of the web app on PythonAnywhere, you need to reload the web app afterwards for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem gets solved if I reload the web app in the 'web tab' of PythonAnywhere.